# Seeing what revision goes with a tag in Git

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, git-tag

Beginner [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) question:

In the [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) world, `hg tags` gives me a list of tags and the corresponding revisions, whereas `git tag` only lists the tag names. How do I see what the matching rev number/hash is?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For full information associated with that tag, use command

```
git show v1.5
```

Or you can see the lightweight information, skipping details, by command

```
git show v1.5 -lw
```

Comment: git log gives you list of revisions. And when you ask revision corresponding to a tag, this is the answer.

Answer (score 9):

If tag in question is so called 'heavyweight tag', or annotated tag, utilizing tag object, e.g. PGP signed version (as far as I know Mercurial doesn't have equivalent) then

```
$ git show v1.5.0
```

would show both tag info (tagger, tagging date, tag message - usually containing PGP signature block), and information about tagged commit.  If you prefer, you can use low-level equivalent:

```
$ git cat-file tag v1.5.0
```

(this would fail if `v1.5.0` is not a tag object).

If tag in question is so called 'lightweight tag', it is simply a reference in `refs/tags/*` namespace. You can use "git show lightweight-tag" to show *a commit* pointed by a given tag.

You can use tag name in every place that expect commit-ish, or tree-ish.

---

If you want more than what "git tag" / "git tag -l" offers, you can use one of the following plumbing (low-level) commands [`git show-refs`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-ref.html):

```
$ git show-ref --tags
$ git show-ref --dereference --tags
```

or [`git for-each-ref`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html), which offer extracting more information with `--format=<format>` option, and sorting with `--sort=<key>` option:

```
$ git for-each-ref refs/tags/
```

You can also (ab)use [`git ls-remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) for this, resulting in output similar to "`git show-ref --dereference --tags`":

```
$ git ls-remote --tags .
```

Comment: ...and if you don't know/care whether the tag is a tag object or a lightweight label but want to see just the commit you can use `git show v1.5.0^{commit}`, or `git rev-parse v1.5.0^{commit}` for a scriptable way to retrieve the commit id.