# what is dereference in the context of git show-ref -d

Tags: git

Here is the man page for [git show-ref -d](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref) . They also have an example at the bottom. Still I am not able to understand what dereference does?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Git, a "normal" (annotated, not lightweight) [tag is an object unto itself](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#_tags), containing metadata and the SHA1 of the object it tags. Chapter [10.2 Git Internals - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) in the Git community book has an illustration of the object model:

[image]

<sup>Legend: yellow - commit object, blue/green - tree object, white - blob object</sup>

So, when you use `git show-ref` on a normal tag, it will normally give you information about the [tag object](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#_tags). With the `-d/--dereference` option, it will dereference the tag into the object the tag refers to, and provide information about it instead.

And a note on lightweight vs. annotated tags, in case you aren't aware of that: a lightweight tag is created by using `git tag <tag name>` (i.e. without any of the metadata-providing options like `-a`, `-s`, or `-u`). It's not a tag object at all, just a [Git reference](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) pointing straight [to the object you've tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614449/what-is-tagging-an-object-which-isnt-a-commit-in-git). If you provide one of those options, you're attaching metadata to the tag, so Git creates a tag object to hold that.

Comment: Good summary.+1 See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194385/seeing-what-revision-goes-with-a-tag-in-git:  "if you don't know/care whether the tag is a tag object or a lightweight label but want to see just the commit you can use `git show v1.5.0^{}`, or `git rev-parse v1.5.0^{}` for a scriptable way to retrieve the commit id."

Comment: VonC's helpful hint probably looks a bit odd to anyone not very familiar with git. The `^{}` suffix is a special notation for tags; it means "dereference the tag repeatedly until you find something besides a tag" - just in case you've done something crazy like tag a tag with a tag.

Comment: true, the notation is odd ;) As for tagging a tag with a tag, one can imagine it could help to add some kind of metadata (like for instance a "promotion level" 'rejected', 'tested', 'released', ...) to an existing tagged commit.