# What is tagging an object which isn't a commit in Git?

Tags: git

The git tag documentation says that you can tag either a commit or an object:

> <commit>
> <object>
> The object that the new tag will refer to, usually a commit. Defaults to HEAD.

And indeed you can take the hash of a blob object and tag it. But I don't understand - what is it good for? what can you do with this tag?

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding here, once you tag a commit or SHA it creates a tag object. Tag's are essentially read-only "branches" used normally as milestones since they are often more friendly than a SHA. E.g either named v1.0 etc or any name you like which is easier to remember once something worked and is often what is used to release a product.

Comment: You can tag anything to give thing a name and to prevent garbage collector to remove unreferenced objects. For example, I store my GPG public key (to verify my signed commits/tags) as a blob and [tag the blob](https://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=blob;f=add-pubkey/add-pubkey-blob-tag).

Comment: @phd Cool, you should give that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tag anything to give thing a name instead of a long cryptic ID and to prevent [garbage collector to remove unreferenced objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50141014/7976758).

For example, I store my GPG public key (to verify my signed commits/tags) as a blob and tag the blob (the technics is described in [Git Book, chapter Git Internals - Git References](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References#_tags)).